# Find all uniq combinations in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have vector of uniq elements. I need to create all unique combinations (of 2 and of 3) of this vector elements. I try to use `expand.grid()` function

```
genes <- c('A', 'B')
expand.grid(genes, genes)
```

but the output contains not uniq elements

```
  Var1 Var2
1    A    A #not uniq
2    B    A
3    A    B #not uniq because we already have B+A combination
4    B    B #not uniq
```

So result in my example must have only 1 row - `B    A` or `A    B`. The same problm with combination of 3

```
> genes = c('A', 'B', 'C')
> expand.grid(genes, genes, genes)
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     A    A    A #not uniq
2     B    A    A #not uniq
3     C    A    A #not uniq
4     A    B    A #not uniq
5     B    B    A #not uniq
6     C    B    A 
7     A    C    A #not uniq
8     B    C    A #not uniq
9     C    C    A #not uniq
10    A    A    B #not uniq
11    B    A    B #not uniq
12    C    A    B #not uniq
13    A    B    B #not uniq
14    B    B    B #not uniq
15    C    B    B #not uniq
16    A    C    B #not uniq
17    B    C    B #not uniq
18    C    C    B #not uniq
19    A    A    C #not uniq
20    B    A    C #not uniq
21    C    A    C #not uniq
22    A    B    C #not uniq
23    B    B    C #not uniq
24    C    B    C #not uniq
25    A    C    C #not uniq
26    B    C    C #not uniq
27    C    C    C #not uniq
```

How can I get all unique combinations of 2 and 3?

**update** with `combn()` not working

```
genes = c('A', 'B', 'C')
combn(genes, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C"
```

If I have `genes = c('A', 'B', 'C')` a want get dataframe with three combinations of pairs

```
  Var1 Var2
1    A    B
2    A    C
3    B    C
```

and another dataframe of 1 combination of triplets if I searching triplets:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     A    B    C
```

something like this

```
uniq_pairs = some_function(genes, 2)
uniq_triplets = some_function(genes, 3)
```

Comment: you might be looking for `combn` i.e `combn(genes, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

If you want a function, try below

```
> f <- function(genes, k) data.frame(t(combn(genes, k)))

> f(genes, 2)
  X1 X2
1  A  B
2  A  C
3  B  C

> f(genes, 3)
  X1 X2 X3
1  A  B  C
```

---

Do you mean `combn`?

```
> genes <- c("A", "B", "C")

> unlist(sapply(2:3, function(k) combn(genes, k, paste0, collapse = "+")))
[1] "A+B"   "A+C"   "B+C"   "A+B+C"
```

Comment: @autumnrustle see my update. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ I update question. Result must by A+B, A+C, B+C for pairs and A+B+C for triplets

Comment: I need it in dataframe. And separate. Something like this - uniq_pairs = some_function(genes, 2)

Comment: f <- function(genes, k) data.frame(t(combn(genes, k))) - it is a solution. I forgot about t() function. Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` with `combn` -

```
genes = c('A', 'B', 'C')

lapply(2:length(genes), function(x) combn(genes, x, paste0, collapse = ' + '))

#[[1]]
#[1] "A + B" "A + C" "B + C"

#[[2]]
#[1] "A + B + C"
```

If you want a single vector as output you can `unlist` the above the output.

Comment: can I get it in separate dataframes uniq_pairs in one dataframes with 2 columns and uniq_triplets in another dataframe with 3 colums?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure: Try `crossing` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

crossing(var1='A', var2='B')

crossing(var1='A', var2='B', var3='C')
```

Output:

```
crossing(var1='A', var2='B')
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     B    
> crossing(var1='A', var2='B', var3='C')
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  var1  var2  var3 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     C
```

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` solution could be

```r
library(purrr)

genes <- c("A", "B", "C")

data.frame(name = c("uniq_pairs", "uniq_triplets"), n = 2:3) %>% 
  split(., f = .$name) %>% 
  map(~ t(combn(genes, .x$n)))
```

returns

```r
$uniq_pairs
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "B"  "C" 

$uniq_triplets
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"
```